# Uniqueness Not Maintained On MYSQL Database Rails 3.2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a simple form submission.

On Model I have added

```
validates_uniqueness_of :field
```

But somehow in my Database I get **records with duplicate value of field**.

And Controller Methods are as Follows

```
def create

    field_obj=Model.find_by_field(params[:model][:field])

    if field_obj.nil?
        @model = Model.new(params[:model])

        if (@model.save && params[:commit] == "submit")
            @model.is_submitted=true
            @model.submitted_timestamp=Time.now
            @model.save

          elsif (@model.save(:validate => false) && params[:commit] == "save")
            @model.last_saved_timestamp=Time.now
            @model.save
        end

        respond_to do |format|
          if (@model.save || (@model.save(:validate => false)))
            format.json { render json: @model, status: :created, location: @model }
            format.js
          else
            format.js
            format.json { render json: @model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end

    else

      @model = Model.find(field_obj.id)

      if (@model.update_attributes(params[:model]) && params[:commit] == "submit")
        @model.is_submitted=true
        @model.save
      end

      respond_to do |format|
        if (@model.update_attributes(params[:model])|| (@model.save(:validate => false)))
          format.js
          format.html { redirect_to @model, notice: 'Model was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        else
          format.js
          format.html { render action: "edit" }
          format.json { render json: @model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end

    end


  end


  def update


    @model = Model.find(params[:id])

    if (@model.update_attributes(params[:model]) && params[:commit] == "submit")
      @model.is_submitted=true
      @model.submitted_timestamp=Time.now
      @model.save
    elsif @model.update_attributes(params[:model], :validate=>false) && params[:commit] == "save"

      @model.save
    end



    respond_to do |format|
      if (@model.update_attributes(params[:model])|| (@model.save(:validate => false)))
        format.js
        # format.html { redirect_to @model, notice: 'Model was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.js
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think rails 3.2 ActiveModel validation defind as

`validates :field, uniqueness: true`

thanks

Comment: I don't think that matters. My problem is that when heavy traffic the duplicate value is inserted.

Comment: your method validates_uniqueness_of  is deprecated, it was using on rails 2.If you make uniqueness then it will not be inserted any duplicate values Please see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness Thanks

Comment: Strangely validates_uniqueness_of has been working perfectly. Only some 300 out of 10,000 had duplicates. And they were because the controller recieved 2-3 simultaneous requests from page.

Comment: here it says it is still valid : http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of